# How do I select the top 3 starting at row 2?

Tags: mysql

I never played with the MySQL syntax so I don't know how to do this right now.

I know in SQL it would be

```
select top 3 cloumn_name
from table_name
```

MySQL

```
select column_name
from table_name
limit 3, 2;
```

can someone explain how limit works?

Comment: one creates a variable

Comment: ooops I over-complicated it, sorry

Answer (score 0):

Use `limit` and `offset`:

```
select t.*
from table_name t
order by ??
limit 3 offset 1;
```

When using `limit` you should generally use `order by`.  In addition, for `offset` purposes, MySQL starts counting at 0 and not 1.